# Genimotion Эмулятор + OpenServer

Tags: java, сервер, localhost

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью эмулятора можно обратится к сайту расположенному в папке /domains/site.ru?

Comment: Ни кто не знает что ль?

Comment: а с браузера как пишете? просто site.ru? Тогда все просто - нужно на своей локальной машине настроить dns сервер. Можно на роутере (если такое позволяет). И прописать этот dns в настройках эмулятора. И все.

Comment: Локальную машину вы имеете в виду VirtualBox?

Comment: я не знаю общую конфигурацию того, где все это запускается.